# Can we really get performance gain with CUDA streams?

Tags: cuda

Theoretically,we should get performance gain when we use streams in CUDA I implemented Gauss-seidel method and surprisingly time required with streams is much greater than without streams.Does anyone have examples where I can see performance gain(except examples given in sample directory of SDK that is not so useful)

Answer (score 2):

CUDA streams enable PCI Express transfers to be performed at the same time as kernel processing.  Due to Amdahl's Law, only workloads that perform equal amounts of data transfer and kernel processing will benefit from CUDA streams.  To determine whether your workload will benefit, profile or add some timing code to your application to see what the theoretical maximum performance benefit would be.

Note that in order to get a performance improvement from CUDA streams, you have to "software-pipeline" the downloads, kernel launches, and uploads.  Do this:

```
foreach stream {
    cudaMemcpyAsync( device[stream], host[stream], ... stream );
}
foreach stream {
    LaunchKernel<<<...stream>>>( ... );
    // you can launch multiple kernels in stream, if desired.
}
foreach stream {
    cudaMemcpyAsync( host[stream], device[stream], ... stream );
}
```

not this:

```
foreach stream {
    cudaMemcpyAsync( device[stream], host[stream], ... stream );
    LaunchKernel<<<...stream>>>( ... );
    cudaMemcpyAsync( host[stream], device[stream], ... stream );
}
```

Comment: "Do this ... not this ..." - why? Do you have any source why this should behave differently than that? Neither makes any difference in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In problems where computing time is significant and all of the data is not inter-dependent. Then you can hide the expensive computing time in already expensive memory transfers.

Note that CUDA can perform memory copy and kernel execution simultaneously, so while one stream is doing memory copy the other can do computations.