# CUDA streams taking longer time

Tags: cuda

Is is possible that streams take longer time than normal CUDA programs?It is guaranteed that chunk of data on which streams are operate are independent and overlapping between kernel execution and data transfer is allowed from device side.

Comment: Are you running in the profiler? The profiler serializes all the calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we really get performance gain with CUDA streams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284680/can-we-really-get-performance-gain-with-cuda-streams)

Comment: @RogerDahl How should I install profiler on linux?

Comment: The profiler should be included with the CUDA Toolkit that you must have installed.  If you're using the 4.1 toolkit, it should be called "nvvp", if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To observe superpositions between streams, you should use the command line profiler with the `conckerneltrace` option. You could also save the profiling output as a .csv file and import it within the Visual Profiler. See the NVIDIA Forum post

[CUDA stream performance](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545476/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-stream-performance/)